# Backlight control not working on Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 with Renoir / AMDGPU

Tags: amd-graphics, brightness, backlight

The brightness (LCD backlight) controls on a Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 (15ARH05, LCD display, AMD Renoir CPU Ryzen 5 4600H, discrete NVIDIA GeForce 1650 Ti Mobile) are not working:

- `Fn` keys show the brightness slider on the display moving.
- `/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness` changes accordingly from 0 to 255.
- The display does not show any brightness change.
- Manually writing to `brightness` does not change the display's brightness either.
- `/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/actual_brightness` stays at **311**. *I figure **this** indicates a problem with the amdgpu driver.*
- The display seems to stay at full brightness always.

Adjustments work fine on Windows 10. The laptop is running:

- Kali Linux Rolling
- `linux-image-5.8.0-kali[23]-amd64` (based on 5.8.14) and custom-built kernels 5.9, 5.9.1 and 5.10-rc1, mostly based off the Kali config
- X with `amdgpu` drivers, discrete graphics unused (proprietary NVIDIA drivers loaded and unloaded for testing).

I have tried booting with various `acpi_backlight` kernel options, which lead to various backlights being available in `/sys/class/backlight/*/brightness`:

- `acpi_backlight=video`: `acpi_video0 acpi_video1 amdgpu_bl0`
- `acpi_backlight=vendor`: `amdgpu_bl0 ideapad`
- `acpi_backlight=native`: `amdgpu_bl0`
- `acpi_backlight=none`: `amdgpu_bl0`

Other things that did not work:

- `acpi_osi=Linux` (no change)
- `acpi_osi=` (hangs at boot)
- BIOS update (no other version available)
- moving `/lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_dmcu.bin` away
- patching [`amdgpu_dm.c`](https://github.com/Aonnghus/renoir-brightness/blob/master/brightness.patch)

I am aware that there has been a number of updates related to backlights for AMDGPUs, like general support and fixes in kernel 5.7.x and updates to the scaling of brightness values >255 in 5.9, but so far this seems not to have helped my case (or possibly, broke more things). I am not looking for:

- software alternatives
- adjusting the gamma values
- using discrete graphics (if it can be avoided)

**What else can I do or look into to gain control of the backlight?**

I came across [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1861925/comments/27) and [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1899626), which seem to suggest that some kernel fixes may have broken other things. **What would be the best place to report that?**

Comment: Hey! I have very similar machine (Legion 5 ARH05/ryzen4800h/1650TI), running ubuntu with mainline kernel 5.9.12 and have the same issue with backlight control, did you solved an issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't so far (up to kernel 5.11.2 and BIOS FCCN16WW). It could be that it worked for a few versions of old kernels (somewhere maybe 5.6.x), which might be a starting point to locate how it broke and how to fix it again.

Comment: Doesn't work in 5.7, didn't yet get custom 5.6.x to boot.

Comment: Seems like [they](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1438) found a workaround, but I didn't tried it yet

Comment: I feel that the BIOS option might help you. Unfortunately, the Ideapad Gaming 3 does not offer GPU selection in BIOS (at least I could not find it), contrary to the Legion 5. I am going to try forcing `caps->aux_support = false;` in kernel driver code, though. Thanks for the link, I think I already went there once before the last answers came in.

Comment: Add that as an answer and I can mark it as correct. Removing lines 2206 to 2209 in `amdgpu_drm.c` as indicated of kernel 5.11.2 and recompiling fixes the backlight for this machine; hopefully a fix will be mainlined for 5.12 of 5.13.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kernels 5.11.7, 5.12-rc3, and later allow the kernel parameter [`amdgpu.backlight=0`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/agd5f/linux/-/commit/fef0bfcacd7da46a6c86d425a72eca711d5215bd) to be passed at boot to fix this issue for Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3, Lenovo Legion 5 and possibly other laptops.

For Debian-based distributions using GRUB the parameter can be added in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="amdgpu.backlight=0"
```

After running `update-grub` and rebooting the backlight controls should work.

Previous kernels required patching: The workaround can be found in a [GitLab issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1438#note_821542). Forcing `caps->aux_support = false;` in [`drivers/gpu/drm/amd/display/amdgpu_dm/amdgpu_dm.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5695e51619745d4fe3ec2506a2f0cd982c5e27a4/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/display/amdgpu_dm/amdgpu_dm.c#L2268) fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem, too. Had the same issue with Thinkpad P14s AMD Gen2 and Ubuntu 21.04/Kernel 5.11.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread trying to fix my own <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys.

My fix was going into BIOS setup and switching the `Foolproof Fn Keys` setting to `[Disabled]`. After saving the changes and restarting, everything is now working as smooth as butter. I hope this helps some of you as well!!

I'm using a Lenovo Yoga 6, but the feature should be on most Lenovo laptops